# Does the green blinking led mean that the Pi 3 is working?

Tags: pi-3, activity-led

I have been using a Pi Hole for some years and it stopped working some months ago.  I had assumed that the power pack in my rack had died.

But it is still not responding to its IP address, on my desk with a new power pack.  I am a newbie on PI, I had my son install Pi Hole on it, and he is overseas now.

- The red led is on
- The green is blinking
- It's not responding to its IPAddress (which is forced by the DHCP based on MAC address).
- I can't see it anywhere on the network in the switch' screens.  And when I use a finger app on my phone.

Does the green blinking led mean that the Pi is actually running?  If so, what would its default IPaddress be?

Comment: do you have a tv or monitor? it's so easy to understand what's going on with one of these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the ACTivity LED shows mmc activity (basically SD Card access) and blinks sporadicly in normal use.

This is not particularly useful and does not guarantee the Pi is working.
In fact regular rapid blinking seems to be a symptom of lockup (I have encountered this many times when my Pi become unresponsive).

The [LED Warning Flash Codes](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#led-warning-flash-codes) can be used to diagnose problems.

The Pi has no "default IPaddress". In a standard installation it is set by DHCP or assumes a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) if no DHCP server is found.

Comment: It looks like the sdcard is damaged.  If I test it on Windows, it fails.  And it fails after a reformat as well.